# Resolving package declaration conflicts in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I created a workbench package that requires Guzzle in it's package specific composer.json. Elsewhere in the project, Guzzle is also required in the main composer.json file because it was already required in multiple places in the project.

As a consequence, after creating my project I now get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare GuzzleHttp\Stream\create()
(
 previously declared
    in C:\www\site.dev\laravel\vendor\guzzlehttp\streams\src\functions.php:14)
    in C:\www\site.dev\laravel\workbench\ecomevo\mypackage\vendor\guzzlehttp\streams\src\functions.php
 on line 40
)
```

How do I prevent such declaration conflicts whilst still autoloading both the package's and the project's required dependencies?

Comment: Are you by chance requiring two different versions?

Comment: The root composer.json has `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0"` and the package specific one has `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4"` and I now realize they are pulling slightly different versions as a consequence. Could that be the problem?

Comment: That could be the problem. Since they are different versions, they are going to each be instantiated. Try making the versions the same and see what happens.

Comment: When I change to match the versions between composer.json files I get the same error, but now composer is throwing it on `composer update`.

Answer (score 0):

In your package, use `class_exists` before trying to instantiate the `Guzzle` class. If it already exists, then it's already been declared and you should be able to go ahead and use it.

http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.class-exists.php

Comment: Composer is doing the instantiating through it's autoload feature.

Comment: Hmmm that's odd that it is throwing that error then. Sorry I wasn't of help.